# Java memory game card flipping not working

Tags: java

I am working on a java memory game, but I have a problem, what I can't solve. If I click on any card, it turns up, after that I click on the second card, but it doesn't turn up. If they matched after the checking the second card flips up.

**Card.class**

```
public class Card{

private int img_x, img_y;
private Img img;
private boolean flipped = false;
private boolean flippable = true;

private static Img back_img;
private static int WIDTH, HEIGHT;

public Card(int img_x, int img_y, img img) {
    this.img_x = img_x;
    this.img_y = img_y;
    this.img = img;
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    if (flipped) {
        g.drawImage(img.getimg(), img_x, img_y, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
    } else {
        g.drawImage(back_img.getimg(), img_x, img_y, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
    }
}

public void flip() {
    if (flippable) {
        this.flipped = !flipped;
    }
}
```

**ClickEvent**

```
 public void clickEvent(int x, int y) {
    for (Card card : cards) {
        if ((card.getImg_x() < x) && (card.getImg_x() + card.getWIDTH() > x)
                && (card.getImg_y() < y) && (card.getImg_y() + card.getHEIGHT() > y)) {
            if (card.isFlippable()) {
                card.flip();
                selectedCards.add(card);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    gamePanel.reapint();
    if (selectedCards.size() == 2) {  // if 2 card flipped up
        checkFlippedCards();  //check the 2 cards' images name, if matched it lock the cards to not flippable
    }
    gamePanel.reapint();
}
```

I spend two days to solve this problem, but I have no clue why is it not working. The same method run when I click to any card but only one card flips up as it should.

**CheckFlippedCards**

```
private void checkFlippedCards() {

    int name1 = selectedCards.get(0).getImgName();
    int name2 = selectedCards.get(1).getImgName();
    if (name1 == name2) {
        score++;
        selectedCards.get(0).setFlippable(false);
        selectedCards.get(1).setFlippable(false);
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Vezerlo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    selectedCards.get(0).flip();
    selectedCards.get(1).flip();

    kivalasztottKartyak.clear();
}
```

Comment: Did you debugged `clickEvent` ? Is it the correct card found with you coordinate condition ?

Comment: Maybe you need to call `card.flip();` instead of `card.fip();` ;)

Comment: can you share your code for checkFlippedCards?

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to have the second card to be displayed as flipped _before_ calling `checkFlippedCards()`? If so you need to repaint the panel before calling that (and you might want to call `checkFlippedCards()` in a worker thread in order to not block the EDT.

Comment: I debugged the clickEvent and it found the correct card.

Comment: Thomas gave you the answer. You've add the sleep into `Check...` so the repaint is only done at the end. Meaning you will never see the second card flipped. You need to do the check on a different Thread to let the GUI repaint the cards flipped then 1s later will flip back (need to repaint again here ;) )

Comment: I call the correct method in the original code, but I have to translate some word before I insert here, because I am Hungarian. :)
I call put the reapaint method before the `checkFlippedCards()` ,but nothing changed

Comment: just as I thought, your problem is in checkFlippedCards... see skw's answer I think it's correct and gives you two best options to proceed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you are flipping the second card, then checking if both cards are equal, if they are then they stay flipped.
The problem is when they are not, as they are flipped back again before the panel is repainted.
The fact that you have a `Thread.sleep` does not mean that it will refresh, because the repainting is also done in the same thread that is sleeping.
What I suggest is to put the checking of cards flipped on another thread so that you can refresh your main thread without it interfering with the repainting.
Another solution would be for you to not flip the cards automatically when they are not equal. So, say, they should be flipped back in the next click. This could be done by moving

```
selectedCards.get(0).flip();
selectedCards.get(1).flip();

kivalasztottKartyak.clear();
```

to the `clickEvent` and just check whether `selectedCards.size() == 2`. In this case you would only flip both cards and not do anything else in this click and get rid of the `sleep`.

Comment: You answer helped a lot. It is working perfectly now. Thank you. :)

Comment: Glad to be able to help :-D